# Highcharts column + line combination chart with multiple series

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, highcharts, spline

[image: This is my multiple bar graph which i m getting]

In my graph I want to add both column graph and line graph(trendline) for count . My code is like this

```
                     var crime_data=[];
                            for(var i=0;i<result.themes.length;i++){
                              var crime={};
                              var test2 = result.themes[i];
                              var test = test2[Object.keys(test2)];
                              console.log("test",test);
                              crime.name = Object.keys(result.themes[i]);
                              crime.data = [];
                                var test1 = test.individualValueVariable;
                                for(var j=0;j<test1.length;j++){
                               crime.data.push(test1[j].count);
                             };
                              crime_data.push(crime);
                            };
        var crimeChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
             renderTo: 'container1',
             type: 'colomn'
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories:year,
                crosshair: true
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Count'
                }
            },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
            }, 
            tooltip: {

                shared: true,
            },
            plotOptions: {

                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    depth: 25,
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    point: {
                            },
  }
        },
            series:crime_data
        });
```

If I add type 'spline ' in series. I am not getting even data and not trend line. Please suggest me how should i add trend line in this case.

And this is my JSON :

```
{
    "boundaries": {
        "boundary": [{
            "boundaryId": "45083021025",
            "boundaryType": "USA_POSTCODE",
            "boundaryRef": "B1"
        }]
    },
    "themes": [{
        "TheftCrimeTheme": {
            "boundaryRef": "B1",
            "individualValueVariable": [{
                "name": "2012 Theft Crime",
                "description": "Theft Crime for 2012",
                "count": 310
            }, {
                "name": "2013 Theft Crime",
                "description": "Theft Crime for 2013",
                "count": 230
            }]
        }
    }, {
        "AssaultCrimeTheme": {
            "boundaryRef": "B1",
            "individualValueVariable": [{
                "name": "2012 Assault Crime",
                "description": "Assault Crime for 2012",
                "count": 50
            }, {
                "name": "2013 Assault Crime",
                "description": "Assault Crime for 2013",
                "count": 41
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

Please suggest me how should I do this.

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts does not have trendline functionality built in. You can use something like: https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/highcharts_trendline
to calculate your trendline values and pass it as to new line series.